# Translating C++ structure to C#

Tags: c#, c++, structure

I have a structure definition in C++ as follows:

```
struct check1
{
  check1(USHORT vaultLen)
  {
    size = sizeof(*this->vaultLen) + vaultLen + sizeof(*this->digestKey);
    buffer = new UCHAR[size];

    this->vaultLen = (USHORT*)buffer;
    this->vaultData = buffer + sizeof(vaultLen);
    this->digestKey = (UCHAR(*)[8])(buffer + sizeof(vaultLen) + vaultLen);

    *(this->vaultLen) = vaultLen;
  }


  USHORT *vaultLen;
  UCHAR *vaultData;
  UCHAR (*digestKey)[8];

  UCHAR* buffer;
  USHORT size;
}
```

I don't wish to use unsafe code so pointers are not allowed.  What would be an equivalent structure in C#? Do the members defined as pointers actually take up space?

With respect to how this struct is used, an object of this struct is created and its size member is passed to an int.

Comment: You could convert it to some format such as JSON or XML. But yes pointers take up space, generally 32 or 64 bits based on your architecture.

Comment: Do you want an equivalent C# structure, an interop class, or something else?

Comment: An equivalent C# structure

Comment: C# has Array and List types that you could Google for, to help you with this

Comment: I'd also add that the conversion depends strongly on the *intent* of the object.  How is it used?

Comment: An object of this struct is created and its size member is passed to an int. Nothing else.

Comment: Except when you convert to C#, the size members are not really necessary ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent C# structure that is not used for interop would look something like:

```
public class check1
{
    public byte[] digestKey = new byte[8];
    public List<byte> vaultData;
}
```

The other members are not necessary as `buffer` is just a memory block to hold `digestKey` and `vaultData`, and the others are size buffers to allow quick access to the proper locations in the buffer for the various data members.

Comment: What about teh size member? Because that's what I ll be using in other functions.

Comment: If you are not planning to use this for interop between unmanaged code, the size members (and size argument to your constructor) are unnecessary.  The only real data members you have in your C++ struct are your `digestKey` and `vaultData` members.  Everything else is used simply to manage the memory (which you don't need to do in C#).

Comment: What would be the size of the vaultData member in your definition? Also, in order to get the size of the whole class, Marshal.SizeOf should be enough?

Comment: That kind of depends on what you mean by "size":  The number of `byte`s will be `vaultData.Count`.  The size of the whole list will be different as it holds other data members (e.g. count).  If you are looking to marshal it to unmanaged code, the solution here would need to be tweaked (hence the note that this would not be used for interop).

Comment: You can create a constructor that takes a length, but it is unnecessary in C# (again, the whole purpose of it in your C++ code is to help with the memory management - which you do not have to do in C#).

Comment: Your declaration of digestKey won't compile - you need "public byte[] digestKey = new byte[8];".